# Travelled to Canada via US (on a return ticket) but returned home on original return flight from Canada is this OK?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, uk-citizens, passport-stamps

Had issues with eTA for entering Canada via air, but travel had already been booked with my family. When I couldn't travel with them made the decision that I needed to get there via the US on my own. I purchased a return ticket to New York and travelled on to Burlington, Vermont and then drove to Canada. I purchased a return ticket to US as it was cheaper than one way. Fortunately I managed to return home from Canada on original planned flight.

Do I now need to notify the US Immigration or similar that I've returned home to the UK or is this already done via my passport?

Comment: When you arrived in the US, did you inform the CBP officer of your travel plans? What did he tell you?

Comment: I do not understand, please clarify the list of countries in order of entry and whether you have been refused travel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need to notify immigration, but unless you stopped by the CBP office at the US-Canadian border to have the exit recorded, it's likely the exit wasn't recorded (on the other hand, it is not uncommon for the Canadians to pass on the information to the US).

As such, there is a small chance that the next time you try to enter they'll want you to show that you didn't overstay the previous time. You can check whether they already recorded your exit at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

If your exit wasn't recorded, you can wait until you reenter and show evidence of your departure if you're challenged, or you can send that evidence (train/bus/air tickets, passport stamps, receipts/bank statements from foreign countries etc.) to:

> Coleman Data Solutions
>   3043 Sanitarium Road, Suite 2
>   Akron, OH  44312
>   United States
>   Attn: NIDPS (I-94)

Comment: Is there still an address on the page? The FAQ dealing with the situation not longer has an address and just says to save evidence of the exit.

Comment: @Dennis https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94